# How to extract the definition of a macro, to write in a file for instance

Tags: macros

I’d like to extract the definition of a macro (ideally defined via any command) in a LaTeX3 string, for instance to write it later in a file. Is it possible?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}



\begin{document}

{
  \NewDocumentCommand{\Hello}{O{}m}{Hello #2 (arg #1).}
  Normal usage: \Hello[hey]{Alice}
  %% This part: put the code used to define the macro in a LaTeX3 string
  %% (I usually can't change how \Hello is defined, so I should only do something here)
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_replace_all:Nnn { Nnx }
  \cs_set:Nn \my_set_hash_robust:Nn {
    \str_set:Nn {#1} {#2}
    \str_replace_all:Nnx {#1} { ## } { \c_hash_str }
  }
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_set_hash_robust:Nn { cn }
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_set_hash_robust:Nn { cx }

  %% This line should be replaced by an automatic code somehow
  \my_set_hash_robust:Nn \l_contentHello_str {\NewDocumentCommand{\Hello}{O{}m}{Hello ~#2~ (arg~ #1).}}
  %%% This part should not really be touched
  \ior_new:N \g_myfile
  \iow_open:Nn \g_myfile {cmd.tex}
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \iow_now:Nn { NV }
  \iow_now:NV \g_myfile {\l_contentHello_str}
  \iow_close:N \g_myfile
  \ExplSyntaxOff
}

\input{cmd.tex}
\Hello[my args]{Bob}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
We are making progress, see here [How to extract the text typed by user in \NewDocumentCommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698442/how-to-extract-the-text-typed-by-user-in-newdocumentcommand/698444)

Comment: that depends on your definition of definition. you could write `\meaning\Hello` but that might not be what you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle by "definition" I mean anything that passes the above MWE by only replacing the set_hash_robust line (ideally it would look like the string typed by the user… but if it is possible). Notably, `\meaning` is not usable (at least not as it) for many reasons: first it does not print much useful information for commands defined with xparse or `newcommand`, only `def` provides something meaningful. Then, even for `def` the output of `\meaning` needs some parsing to reconstruct the actual definition, for instance it is written `macro:ARGS->DEF.`, and making it robust might not be easy

Comment: There is no way in TeX to get the catcodes of the parameter part of a macro, and one cannot rely on the replacement text having 'predictable' catcodes. Look for example at how `etoolbox` does patching, where if 'current' catcodes don't work in an `\ifx` sense it gives up. So we likely need more info on what you really need to do to even say if it's doable.

Comment: @JosephWright I’m fine with forgetting about catcode. The application I have in mind is for my robust-externalize library: to cache e.g. pictures, it writes it in a file and separately compiles that file. The problem is that the figure might contain macro defined before: you have many solutions right now to avoid this issue (either input a common file (tracked or not), use `add to preamble={\def\Hello{copy the def here}}`), but this is not ideal, as it either requires you to duplicate code, add impurity (untracked file) or do unnecessary recompilation (tracked file). I’d prefer `forward=Hello`

Comment: (PS: I guess it certainly cannot work for all cases… but I’d like it to work for simpler cases, e.g. if people use newcommand, def or NewDocumentCommand: one solution might be to redefine from the start `\NewDocumentCommand` to save its argument in another macro and rescan it, but people would certainly be horrified if I redefine NewDocumentCommand.)

Comment: @tobiasBora but xparse (or even `\newcommand` if used with optional arguments) is just an instance of the general problem of how deep do you want to go. if you have `\def\xa{1} \def\xb{\xa} \def\xc{\xb}` and the figure you are externalising uses `\xc` what do you want to write out?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was thinking to provide two versions, one that just writes `\def\xc{\xb}`, and the user might as well run `forward=xb` if they wish, and one that evaluate `\xc`, but this is actually simpler and I guess only works for macros that take no argument. So let's say here that I want to deal with the first case. (Actually, if it is possible to even get the closure of a macro that would be cool, but I guess it is not trivial, and I guess it is hard to know where to stop)

Comment: But for commands like NewDocumentCommand, of course I don't want to simply copy the dummy content of `\Hello` since it is useless alone, I want to get everything needed to run it like if I had copied the definition

Comment: But you don't know that that *is* simple, because you don't know `\xc` doesn't absorb one or more arguments just from `\def\xc{\xb}`. What if also `\def\xb#1#2#3{#1 and #2 and #3}`, so that `\xc` absorbs three arguments, even though `\def\xc{\xb}` doesn't make that obvious?

Comment: @cfr I don't see the problem, I would simply write `\def\xc{\xb}` to the file. And the simpler expanded version would be a different command, like `forward expanded=xc`, if the macro can't be expanded I give an error.

Comment: What I mean is, you can't tell whether this is a 'simple' case (no argument) or a non-simple case (complex argument specification). And by `evaluate` do you mean 'expand once', 'expand twice', 'expand until only non-expandable tokens remain'? or?

Comment: @cfr but why do you need to know? I just want to write the current definition of the macro in a file (forgetting about catcodes), basically what `\meaning` is giving but parsed and robust for xparse/newcommand. Let's forget about the expanded version for now (but in practice I can imagine writting different versions depending on the expand strategy).

Comment: When you write a string of tokens to external text file for reading that file later, then you always face at least two problems: 1. How to guarantee that at the time of reading things get tokenized in the correct catcode-régime? (It might even be the case that you cannot get that by just reading and tokenizing as the string might have been made up in several steps and therefore contain explicit character tokens of same character code but different category.)  2. How to guarantee that all definitions/meanings needed for expansion/correct processing  are available when reading in?

Comment: I think in LuaTeX you can probably handle the first problem, but not the second.

Comment: I just meant that you can't distinguish 'simple' and non-'simple' cases in the way your comment seemed to suggest. By the way, in the part of the code you say shouldn't be changed, you are misusing `V`. You don't want `{` `}` around the variable or else you don't need a variant and just use `n`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez well I already said that it is the role of the user to export all macros, and that I don't care so much about catcode issues as my examples are simple enough (and if I really need it I could provide different commands for special cases like "makeatletter" etc…). Most of my use-cases concern simple definitions like `\newcommand\adv{\mathcal{A}}` or `\NewDocumentCommand{\myIcon}{m}{\tikz\node[fill=red]{#1};}`. In these cases I'd like to write these two commands in the file, and the user well be in charge of loading tikz separately.

Comment: (Or maybe you mean that catcodes do play a role in my examples?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to the pointer of egreg in [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698442/how-to-extract-the-text-typed-by-user-in-newdocumentcommand/698444#698444), I managed to make it work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_replacement_spec:N { c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_argument_spec:N { c }

\cs_new:Nn \__myModule_getCommandDefinitionFromXparse:N
{
  \str_clear_new:N \l__myModule_definition_str
  \GetDocumentCommandArgSpec { #1 }
  \str_set:Nx \l__myModule_definition_str {
    \c_backslash_str DeclareDocumentCommand
    \c_left_brace_str
    \c_backslash_str \cs_to_str:N #1
    \c_right_brace_str
    \c_left_brace_str \ArgumentSpecification \c_right_brace_str
    \c_left_brace_str
    \cs_replacement_spec:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 ~ code }
    \c_right_brace_str
  }%
}

\cs_new:Nn \__myModule_getCommandDefinitionFromDef:N
{
  \str_clear_new:N \l__myModule_definition_str
  \str_set:Nx \l__myModule_definition_str {
    \c_backslash_str def \c_backslash_str \cs_to_str:N #1
    \cs_argument_spec:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
    \c_left_brace_str
    \cs_replacement_spec:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 }
    \c_right_brace_str
  }%
}

\def\myModule@extractDefaultNewcommand#1#2#3#4{
  #4%
}%

\cs_new:Nn \__myModule_getCommandDefinitionFromNewcommand:N
{
  \str_clear_new:N \l__myModule_definition_str
  \str_clear_new:N \l_myModule_tmp
  %% \l_myModule_tmp will look like [#1]#2#3#4#5#6#7:
  \str_set:Nx \l_myModule_tmp {\cs_argument_spec:c { \c_backslash_str \cs_to_str:N #1 }}%
  %% We remove the brackets:
  \str_replace_all:Nnn \l_myModule_tmp {[} {}
  \str_replace_all:Nnn \l_myModule_tmp {]} {}
  \str_set:Nx \l__myModule_definition_str {
    %% this line will be like "\newdocumentcommand{\mymacro}"
    \c_backslash_str newcommand \c_left_brace_str \c_backslash_str \cs_to_str:N #1 \c_right_brace_str
    %% It must have at least one argument, since elements without optional arguments are turned into \def
    %% Moreover, macros can't have more than 1 argument, so it will be easier to parse, we just need the last digit
    [\str_range:Nnn \l_myModule_tmp {-1} {-1}] %% <- this is the number of mandatory arguments
    [\expandafter \myModule@extractDefaultNewcommand #1 ] %% <- this is the value of the default argument
    \c_left_brace_str
    \cs_replacement_spec:c { \c_backslash_str \cs_to_str:N #1 }
    \c_right_brace_str
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myModuleGetCommandDefinition}{m}{
  \cs_if_exist:NTF #1 {
    \cs_if_exist:cTF {\cs_to_str:N #1 ~ code}{
      % xparse-based definition
      \__myModule_getCommandDefinitionFromXparse:N #1%
      \l__myModule_definition_str%
    } {
      \cs_if_exist:cTF {\c_backslash_str \cs_to_str:N #1}{
        % \newcommand-based definition
        \__myModule_getCommandDefinitionFromNewcommand:N #1
        \l__myModule_definition_str%
      }{
        % \def-based definition
        \__myModule_getCommandDefinitionFromDef:N #1
        \l__myModule_definition_str%
      }
    }
  }{
    \PackageError{myModule}{The~macro~#1~does~not~exist}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This works for xparse-based definitions:

\NewDocumentCommand{\testXparse}{O{default}m}{Hey (#1) #2 you are nice.}
\texttt{\myModuleGetCommandDefinition{\testXparse}}\\

This works for simple def:

\def\testDef[#1]#2{I am #1 from #2 in a def.}
\texttt{\myModuleGetCommandDefinition{\testDef}}\\

This works now for simple newcommand-based definitions:

\newcommand{\testNewcommand}[7][mydefaultvalue]{From newcommand (#1) #2 seems to work.}
\texttt{\myModuleGetCommandDefinition{\testNewcommand}}\\

If we do not put any default value, it is equivalent to a def:\\
\newcommand{\testNewcommandNoDefault}[2]{From newcommand (#1) #2 seems to work.}
\texttt{\myModuleGetCommandDefinition{\testNewcommandNoDefault}}

Test without optional argument:

\newcommand{\testNewcommandNoOpt}[7]{From newcommand (#1) #2 without optional arguments.}
\texttt{\myModuleGetCommandDefinition{\testNewcommandNoOpt}}\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is impressive, but have you tried it for `\bfseries` and `\textbf`, for example? (Ignoring catcodes.) I guess you just give an error for font commands ...?

Comment: @cfr Thanks. I get `\def\bfseries{\protect \bfseries}`, which seems a bit circular ^^' But anyway this is not really the use case I have, I don't expect this to work for any weird macro that depends on other macro, in that case my user would better just load the library that defines it. It is mostly useful for simple user-defined macros (even if I made a command to add `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around to also deal with some sort commands that need a special catcode for @)

Comment: And if you mean to use `\bfseries` inside a command, this works without any issue.

Comment: Seems fair enough. You just have to document it, I guess. But standard font commands are hardly 'weird' from a user perspective, so you'll likely need to come up with some other description ;). Before you read the next bit, remember not to shoot the messenger! `\GetDocumentCommandArgSpec` has been removed from the kernel development code and will disappear in the next update. This was raised as an issue for `memoize` on GitHub. If you look at the transcript from yesterday's TeX SE chat, you'll find the discussion.

Comment: @cfr yeah, a user reported it to me here https://github.com/leo-colisson/robust-externalize/issues/6 Apparently, calling `\usepackage{xparse}` should be enough if my understanding is correct?

Comment: Yes, though the documentation says it's no longer needed. Another option is to copy the code. (Presumably in such a way that it won't give errors if somebody loads another package which does the same e.g. use a unique name.) Various options were discussed. The official answer to, 'what should my package do instead?' is apparently 'not do this'.

Comment: What is the "this" here?

Comment: Depend on the argument specification, since it is not reliable. So the answer to 'what should I use instead?' is 'nothing, because you shouldn't do the kind of thing `\Get...` does in the first place'. At least, that's how I understood it. After discussion, I think the conclusion is they don't want the thing in the kernel because, if it is in the kernel, people will expect it to work reliably and it cannot be expected to work reliably. Hence, they're exiling it in `xparse`, which is deprecated but still there. Copying the code or loading `xparse` are the options I remember.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't want not to use it since I want this functionality, but I get that it might not be 100% reliable, e.g. if def contains an arrow like ->. So I’ll load xparse for now, thanks for this!