# How to extract the text typed by user in \NewDocumentCommand

Tags: xparse

In order to solve [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697120/how-to-extract-the-definition-of-a-macro-to-write-in-a-file-for-instance), let us start from a simpler task: how could I get the text typed by the user when defining a `\NewDocumentCommand`, to get a result close to what I would get when typing `\meaning` on a macro defined with `\def`? I guess it should be defined in some weirdly named macro, but I’m unable to find its name, and reading the source of xparse is… hard.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\def\test[#1]#2{Hey (#1) #2 you are nice.}

\NewDocumentCommand{\testXparse}{O{}m}{Hey (#1) #2 you are nice.}

\begin{document}

\test[Alice]{Bob}
\show\test

This corresponds to what the user typed. Great.
\texttt{\meaning\test}\\

\testXparse[Alice]{Bob}
\show\testXparse

This does NOT correspond to what the user typed. Not great.
\texttt{\meaning\testXparse}


\end{document}
```

PS: let’s keep things simple: I do NOT care about catcode, or complicated edge cases.

**EDIT**
Oh, I found it:

```
\texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname testXparse code\endcsname}
```

gives me:

```
\protected\long
macro:#1#2->Hey (#1) #2 you are nice.
```

!!
Now let’s try to find how to put this in a string, extract the arguments, and do the same for `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in `\testXparse code` (with a space in the name).

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\retrievexparsedefinition}{m}
 {
  \texttt{\cs_replacement_spec:c { \cs_to_str:N #1 ~ code }}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\testXparse}{O{}m}{Hey (#1) #2 you are nice.}

\begin{document}

\retrievexparsedefinition{\testXparse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can get the same in the console by doing

```
\ShowCommand{\testXparse}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I can't compile, I get `ERROR: Undefined control sequence. \cs_replacement_spec:c`. Do I need some weird unstable features? If so, is there a way to have it working on less recent latex distributions? (I don't want to have errors e.g. when uploading the document to arxiv)

Comment: (ps: my goal is to write it in a latex3 string to put it in a string, so `\cs_replacement_spec:c` might not even be needed?)

Comment: @tobiasBora That's dated from February 2019. It is definitely not in the experimental category, which I assume is what you mean by 'weird unstable' ;).

Comment: Uhm, I have texlive 2022 and still can't compile…

Comment: Oh, I understand what is going wrong: the `:N` is valid but not the `:c`, so I needed to add `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_replacement_spec:N { c }` to make it work! Thanks!

Comment: Note also the `\cs_argument_spec:N` to get the argument spec.

Comment: So I managed to get what I wanted for `\def`-based and xparse-based macros, but I am still struggling with commands created with `\newcommand`. If you know how to do the same for this, I created a follow up question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698653/get-text-typed-by-user-in-newcommand

Comment: I finally managed to make it work for any xparse/def/newcommand based command, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698442/how-to-extract-the-text-typed-by-user-in-newdocumentcommand/698444#698444